# Customizing colorbar border color on matplotlib

Tags: colors, matplotlib, border

how can I change the colorbar borders so that they are white and not black (externals border and between each segment)?

For example:

```
x=randint(100, size=(10,10))
cs=contourf(x)
cb=colorbar(cs)
```

give

[image]

but I want :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, you can even make it transparent by `cb.outline.set_visible(False)` rather than white.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

edit:
Notice the comments below for MPL 1.3 and later.

Add:

```
cb=colorbar(cs, drawedges=True)

cb.outline.set_color('white')
cb.outline.set_linewidth(2)

cb.dividers.set_color('white')
cb.dividers.set_linewidth(2)
```

Comment: Maybe it's a new version of matplotlib (1.4.3), but I had to use `cb.outline.set_edgecolor('white')`.

Comment: @PiQuer, you are correct. In MPL 1.3 (i think), the outline is changed from a `Line` object to a `Polygon` object. Using `set_color`, affects both **edge** and **facecolor**, but since a `Line` doesnt have a **facecolor**, it used to work fine. Now setting the **edgecolor** specifically, as you suggest,  is the way to go. Thanks for the update. See: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2352

Answer (score 13):

As PiQuer mentioned:

```
cb.outline.set_edgecolor('white')
```

works nowadays