# matplotlib can't add colorbar border

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, border, colorbar

I have tried `drawedges=True` and `cbar.outline.set_visible(True)` to make colorbar border visible. But no use.

```
cbar = fig.colorbar(
       cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=mycmap, norm=mynorm),
       ax=ax,
       shrink=0.2,
       aspect=10,
       anchor=(0.0, 0.1),
       pad=0,
       drawedges=True,
       ticks=[0, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]    
       )
cbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '100', '1000', '2000', '3000', '> 4000'])
cbar.ax.tick_params(size=4)
# cbar.outline.set_visible(True)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Many thanks.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477696/customizing-colorbar-border-color-on-matplotlib

Comment: @Davide_sd thanks for the suggestion. I have also tried `cbar.outline.set_edgecolor('black')` and `cbar.outline.set_color('black')`. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have solved this problem by removing `plt.style.use('seaborn')`. I hope it helps if anyone has the same problem and thank you all for your interest in this matter.